# How do I play background music in Slick/LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl, music, slick

I'm trying to play music in the background for my opening menu, but cant seem to find a tutorial specifically on how to play a music file. Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
    Music openingMenuMusic = new Music("res/openingMenuMusic.ogg");

    openingMenuMusic.loop();
}
```

http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Music.html